# CodeMirror - PHP Mode Not Working?

Tags: php, css, codemirror

For some reason its not displaying the text to be highlighted or anything, not sure why.

Links:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../../doc/docs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../../lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../../lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../../addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../css/css.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/../clike/clike.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/php/php.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
  .CodeMirror { height: 400px; width: 500px; border-radius:6px; padding-top:3px; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
  .CodeMirror-scroll { max-height: 400px; width:500px; }
  .CodeMirror pre { display:inline-block; padding-left: 7px; line-height: 1.25; }
```

Script:

```
  <script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("demotext"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "text/x-php",
        indentUnit: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        enterMode: "keep",
        tabMode: "shift"
    });
  </script>
```

Its displaying weirdly and not working D:

[image]

Need more information? Let me know!

Comment: Note: anyone using a theme other than default will need to load it in. Also for PHP, be sure you are using **all** JS files in the codemirror PHP demo. http://codemirror.net/mode/php/index.html It needs six total. For good reasons, I'm sure.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps someone else,
it not work because you need open php tag **<?php**,
but .. you can do it without, just set mode, like that:

```
mode: {
    name: 'php',
    startOpen: true
}
```

Comment: This wins for me. Tx

Comment: Love you, this helped a lot x, oh wait actually for me it was `{ plain: true }` but still love u

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, if it's not a copy'replace error during preparing your code for stackoverflow, then the include is wrong: "mode/php/../../lib/codemirror.js". I would suggest checking your includes.

For a working example, you might take a look at: 
https://raw2.github.com/jakoch/editor/master/index.php

You find a working example over at Github. Feel free to contribute: https://github.com/jakoch/editor

Comment: Thank you. Although the error handling could be improved a bit ,)

Answer (score 2):

```
codemirror/mode/clike/clike.js
```

make sure you include this js in order for the syntax highlighting to works

Answer (score 1):

You need to add PHP tags

```
<?php
     $var = "Hello";
     print $var;
?>
```